# Azure APIM Service Docs for 3rd Party Auth Token

Tags: azure, bearer-token, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I apologize if the title is incorrect or misleading. I'm not even sure Azure APIM can handle what I'm trying to do.

I'll start from the 3rd party API I'm trying to access. The name of the service doesn't matter but for the sake of this sample we'll call it "EdibleThunder".

EdibleThunder API uses a typical Bearer Token for API Authorization. You would use a Client Id & Client Secret to retrieve a JWT Auth Token. We'll pretend that the end point is:

```
https://auth.ediblethunder.io/connect/token
```

In cURL the request would look something like this:

```
curl --location 'https://auth.ediblethunder.io/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={{client id removed for security}}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={{secret removed for security}}' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
```

The response would look something like this:

```
{
   "access_token":"eJhbGci01...iIIWgsrA",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "scope":"item"
}
```

I can then take my Bearer Token and make a call to the API End Point to get some work done. That would like something like this:

```
curl --location 'https://api.ediblethunder.io/items/adjustments' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eJhbGci01...iIIWgsrA' \
--data '{
   "items": [
      {
         "id":"123", 
         "adjust":-2
      }, 
      {
         "id":"456", 
         "adjust":3
       }
   ]}'
```

I would like to have an APIM End Point to proxy the call to the "adjustments" end point without having my client go through the process of getting a Bearer Token.

Does APIM Services have the capability of handling that behind the scenes? If so, can someone point me to a tutorial or documentation to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for you help.